# Не считывает дальше строку после пробела

Tags: c

Пытаюсь считать с файла текст , но он не считывается дальше первого пробела в тексте.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char num1[450];
    int A[450];
    int A1[450];
    int j = 0;
    char num2[450] = {0};
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    freopen("C:\\Users\\Elvin\\source\\repos\\atoi\\Text.txt", "r", stdin);
        scanf("%s", num1);

    puts(num1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что попросили - `%s` - то и делает: одно слово.

Хотите строку? `fgets`, `gets_s` к вашим услугам. Только просто `gets` не вздумайте использовать - чревато переполнением буфера...

Comment: ,while (fgets(num1,450, fp) != NULL)
  printf("%s", num1);   В отладчике смотрю - вижу , что текст в памяти записан, но пишу puts(num1); и на экран не выводится весь текст

Comment: В нем точно нет нулевого символа посредине? :)

Comment: ,да,там он был,вроде исправил

Comment: ,вопрос немного не по теме , если я хочу текст из символов ascii перевести  в его десятичные коды , то можно делать прямое преобразование типа ? Вот такое : A[i]=int(num1[i++]);

Comment: Можно даже не писать `int`. Что до `i` и `i++` - то тут уж вы смотрите сами, где они должны быть и в каком виде...